# EXACT measurements of a circle. Possible?

Tags: pi

I understand simple circle equations like c=pi×d and a=pi×(rr) (sorry keyboard doesn't have pi or exponents) if pi is irrational with an infinitely long decimal, doesn't that make it impossible to exactly measure either c or d or a or both? I understand for practical terms we use 3.14 as an approximation. Does this mean all measurements derived from pi are approximations. I can imagine a diameter being exactly say 1 meter. Does that mean that the circumference will have intimate decimals too, ie impossible yo measure EXACTLY.  My idea is that either d or c can be exactly measured but not both. Please feel free to confirm my ideas or drop knowledge on me. I am a layman so please nothing too crazy

Comment: Well, if you are speaking of practical reality, even your $1$ meter is an approximation.  Your measuring stick is only approximate, and the resolution of your eyes (or whatever tool you substitute) is also only approximate.

Comment: Also consider: Let $d=\frac 1{\sqrt {\pi}} \implies c=\sqrt {\pi}$. Thus sometimes neither of them can be measured exactly.

Comment: Few if any of us have $\pi$ or exponents on our keyboards. The site provides a way to write well-formatted math formulas with just the characters on an ordinary keyboard. To see how, you can start here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing "can be measured" with "is a rational number".  No length can be measured exactly as measuring is a physical process with real world limitations.  All measurements, derived from $\pi$ or not, are approximations.  You are correct that as $\pi$ is irrational, at least one of the radius and circumference of a circle must be irrational.  In mathematics, if we say the diameter of a circle is $1$ unit, the circumference is exactly $2\pi$ units.  The fact that this number is irrational does not make it approximate.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical arguments are about concepts in our heads, not about measurements made with yardsticks or tape measures. If we talk about the number $\pi$, the diameter $d$, or the circumference $c$ of a circle we consider $\pi$, $d$, or $c$ as *real numbers*, i.e., as elements of the system ${\mathbb R}$. As such they are defined,  given, or to be computed with "infinite precision". The elements of ${\mathbb R}$ can be integer,  rational, or irrational. An integer number can be encoded as $\pm$ a finite decimal number without loss of information, and a rational number can be encoded as a fraction ${p\over q}$ with $p\in{\mathbb Z}$, $q\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$. It is true that $\pi$ or $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be represented by such means in finite terms, but they are well defined as elements of ${\mathbb R}$ with "infinite precision" via certain formulas, e.g.,
$$\pi:=4\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\>dx\>,\qquad \sqrt{2}:={\rm the}\bigl\{x\in{\mathbb R}\bigm| x>0\>\wedge\>x^2=2\bigr\}\ .$$

For daily life these things are not much of a problem since we can always work with finite decimal (in particular: rational) approximations to any real number we can think of, and arrive at good numerical results. This comes from the fact that the basic operations in ${\mathbb R}$ ($+$, $-$, $\cdot$, and $:$) are continuous.